# Problem with ContentPage Rotation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I'm working on some feature for my new project where I've a content page that I need to show always in Portrait. I already achieved it by implementing custom renderers and overriding `OnWindowVisibilityChanged` for Android, (I've not go into iOS at this moment). The problem is when i go to a new page from the Portrait one, the next one must support both orientations, however it only shows in Portrait.

I suppose there is a way to achieve this without implementing custom renderers for each page that i need to show after the one with fixed orientation.

Any suggestions?

Here is my overriding implementation of `OnWindowVisibilityChanged`

```
protected override void OnWindowVisibilityChanged([GeneratedEnum] ViewStates visibility)
{
    base.OnWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);

    var activity = (Activity)Context;

    if (visibility.Equals(ViewStates.Gone))
    {
        // go back to previous orientation
        activity.RequestedOrientation = _previousOrientation;
    }
    else if (visibility.Equals(ViewStates.Visible))
    {
        if (_previousOrientation.Equals(ScreenOrientation.Sensor))
        {
            _previousOrientation = activity.RequestedOrientation;
        }

        activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer for the problem you define please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one plugin called Xamarin.Plugin.DeviceOrientation
you can use this, this will solve your problem easily.

for example, look at this switch condition

```
switch (orientation)
        {
            case DeviceOrientations.Free:
                CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.UnlockOrientation();
                break;
            case DeviceOrientations.Landscape:
                CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.LockOrientation(Plugin.DeviceOrientation.Abstractions.DeviceOrientations.Landscape);
                break;
            case DeviceOrientations.Portrait:
                CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.LockOrientation(Plugin.DeviceOrientation.Abstractions.DeviceOrientations.Portrait);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

for only one page you can call this on onApperaing()
`CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.LockOrientation(Plugin.DeviceOrientation.Abstractions.DeviceOrientations.Portrait);`

and again to free the orientation  call this on onDiappearing()

`CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.UnlockOrientation();`

for more information and how to use visit this link,https://github.com/wcoder/Xamarin.Plugin.DeviceOrientation

Comment: Hi @sudesh, the issue isn't on having both orientation on my app, I already have it. The problem is I need one specific page to show only in portrait, and I already have it too The problem appears when I continue navigating from this specific page with fixed orientation, all other pages after this one are shown only in portrait, and they must be shown in both orientations.

Comment: @SaimelSaez I have updated my answer please look at once. if I m not wrong this will solve your problem. if not please let me know the exact problem.

Comment: Why is "for only one page" approach throwing a system null reference exception?